# Why does pandoc convert "<br>" to "+ \n" on html to asciidoc conversion?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert HTML to asciidoc using pandoc but pandoc converts `<br>` tags into `+\n` instead of `\n` like the following.I also tried asciidoc-escaped_line_breaks but nothing changed.

Terminal Command:

```
`pandoc +RTS -K100000000 -RTS --wrap=preserve -f html -t asciidoc-escaped_line_breaks "input.html" -o "output.asciidoc"`
```

input.html

```
s
<br>
s
```

output.asciidoc

```
s +
s
```

Expected Output:

```
s
s
```

Version:pandoc 1.19.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `escaped_line_breaks` extension is currently only implemented for markdown, not for AsciiDoc.

You could use a [pandoc lua filter](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) like the following, to strip all `LineBreak` elements from the document:

```
function LineBreak()
  return {}
end
```

Save this to e.g. `strip-linebreaks.lua`. Note that you have a really old pandoc version, you need a newer one to use lua filters. Then:

```
pandoc -f html --lua-filter strip-linebreaks.lua -t asciidoc
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Ubuntu and the latest pandoc package version is " 1.19.2.4".(When I try `sudo apt-get upgrade pandoc` I get  _pandoc is already the newest version (1.19.2.4~dfsg-1build4)._)Should do I build it from source for the last version?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that lua extension but it deletes line breaks(<br>) and instead of converting it \n then I tried `function LineBreak()
  return {"\n"}
end` end this returns _Error running filter strip-linebreaks.lua:
Could not read list: Could not get Inline value: untagged value_

Comment: A single newline doesn't have any meaning in AsciiDoc, so it shouldn't matter. See https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#paragraphs